# Querying array element in node property

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes within a the graph with property `pathway` storing an array of of values ranging from

```
path:ko00030
path:ko00010
.
.
path:koXXXXX
```

As an example, (i'm going to post in the batch import format:https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20)

```
ko:string:koid  name    definition      l:label pathway:string_array    pathway.name:string_array
ko:K00001       E1.1.1.1, adh   alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1]      ko             path:ko00010|path:ko00071|path:ko00350|path:ko00625|path:ko00626|path:ko00641|path:ko00830
```

the subsequent nodes might have a different combination of pathway values.

How do i query using CYPHER to retrieve all nodes with `path:ko00010` in `pathway`

the closest i've gotten is using the solution provided for a different problem:
[How to check array property in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118956/how-to-check-array-property-in-neo4j)

```
match (n:ko)--cpd 
Where has(n.pathway) and all ( m in n.pathway where m in ["path:ko00010"])
return n,cpd;
```

but here only nodes with pathways matching exactly to the list provided are returned.

ie. if i were to query `path:ko00010` like in the example above, I'll only be able to retrieve nodes holding `path:ko00010` as the only element in the `pathway` property and not nodes containing `path:ko00010` as well as other `path:koXXXXX`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query the extension of the predicate `ALL` is all the values in the property array, meaning that your query will only return those cases where every value in the `pathway` property array are found in the literal array `["path:ko00010"]`. If I understand you right you want the opposite, you want to test that all values in the literal array `["path:ko00010"]` are found in the property array `pathway`. If that's indeed what you want you can just switch their places, your `WHERE` clause will then be

```
WHERE HAS(n.pathway) AND ALL (m IN ["path:ko00010"] WHERE m IN n.pathway)
```

It is not strictly correct to say that your query only matches cases where the array you ask for and the property array are exactly the same. You could have had more than one value in the literal array, something like `["path:ko00010","path:ko00020"]`, and nodes with only one one of those values in their pathway array would also have matched–as long as all values in the property array could be found in the literal array. Conversely, with the altered `WHERE` filter that I've suggested, the query will match any node that has all of the values of the literal array in their pathway property.

If you want to filter the matched patterns with an array of values where all of them have to be present, this is good. In your example you only use one value, however, and for those queries there is no reason to use an array and the `ALL` predicate. You can simply do

```
WHERE HAS(n.pathway) and "path:ko00010" IN n.pathway
```

If in some context you want to include results where any of a set of values are found in the pathway property array you can just switch from `ALL` to `ANY`

```
WHERE HAS(n.pathway) AND ANY (m IN ["path:ko00010","path:ko00020"] WHERE m IN n.pathway)
```

Also, you probably don't need to check for the presence of the pathway property, unless you have some special use for it you should be fine without the `HAS(n.pathway)`.

And once you've got the queries working right, try to switch out literal strings and arrays for parameters!

```
WHERE {value} IN n.pathway
// or
WHERE ALL (m IN {value_array} WHERE m IN n.pathway)
// or
WHERE ANY (m IN {value_array} WHERE m IN n.pathway)
```

Comment: Awesome response jjaderberg, thanks for the explanation. Really like your response for for switching out literal strings and arrays for parameters! 

I would presume by using parameters you mean using values/parameters obtained from the an earlier section of the same query?

Comment: You can read about parameters here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-parameters.html  http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-cypher-parameters-java.html  http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-cypher.html